# Java program printing out 0 instead of a percentage

Tags: java, file, input, joptionpane

I'm doing a project and this part of the program isn't working. It asks for an inputted character, then it reads a textfile that is given, and outputs a percentage of that letter occurring in the textfile. Here's the code:

```
public static void inputLetterFrequency() {
    String letterInput = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please input a letter to find out the frequency");
    letterInput.toUpperCase();
    char c = letterInput.charAt(0);
    content = content.toUpperCase();

    for (int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++) {
        if (content.charAt(i) == c) {
            letterOccurence++;
        }
    }

    letterFrequency = (letterOccurence / numberCharacters) * 100.0;

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Frequency of letter " + c + " is " + letterFrequency + "%");
    String tryAgain = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please choose an option: \n1 to input another letter \n2 to exit ");
    int n = Integer.parseInt(tryAgain);
    if (n == 1) {
        CharacterAnalyzer.inputLetterFrequency();
    } else {
        System.exit(0);
    }
```

The following are declared at the start of the file

```
public static int numberCharacters;
public static String Filename = UserPrompt.content;
public static int letterOccurence;
public static double letterFrequency;
public static int digitOccurence;
public static double digitFrequency;
```

Answer (score 6):

This is your code that calculates `letterFrequency`: -

```
letterFrequency = (letterOccurence / numberCharacters) * 100.0;
```

Just change the above code to: -

```
letterFrequency = letterOccurence * 100.0 / numberCharacters;
```

---

In the first code: - `(letterOccurence / numberCharacters)` will be evaluated first, and since this is an `integer division`, its result will be `0`, if `numerator` is less than `denominator`.

To make it a `floating-point division`, just multiply the numerator with `100.0` before `dividing` it.